# QUEX_PATH issue while using tokenizer

Tags: c++, makefile, tokenize, make-install, quex

I'm trying to install trainable-tokenizer. I have installed all the dependencies as per the README. this is trainable-tokenizer https://github.com/jirkamarsik/trainable-tokenizer. i have installed quex.deb using installer from quex.org which is a dependency for trainable-tokenizer.

when i try to do `sudo make install` i get the following error

```
ThinkPad-T430:~/tmp/OpenFST/tokenizer/trainable-tokenizer/src$ sudo make install 
[  6%] Building FeaturesReader with quex
Environment variable QUEX_PATH has not been defined.
error: environment variable 'QUEX_PATH' is not defined.
error: your system is 'posix'.
error: if you are using bash-shell, append the following line
error: to your '~/.bashrc' file:
error:
error: export QUEX_PATH=directory-where-quex-has-been-installed
make[2]: *** [quex_files/trtok_read_features_FeaturesReader] Error 255
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/trtok.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

but i have already set up the QUEX_PATH.

```
ThinkPad-T430:~/tmp/OpenFST/tokenizer/trainable-tokenizer/src$ echo $QUEX_PATH 
/opt/quex/quex-0.65.4/
ThinkPad-T430:~/tmp/OpenFST/tokenizer/trainable-tokenizer/src$ ll /opt/quex/quex-0.65.4/
total 68
drwxrwxr-x 5 root root  4096 May 25 17:42 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root  4096 May 25 17:42 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   181 Oct 13  2013 COPYRIGHT.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 May 25 17:42 demo/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Feb 26 02:01 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26424 Oct 13  2013 LGPL.txt*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 25 17:42 manpage/
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 May 25 18:02 quex/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3098 Oct 13  2013 quex.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  2649 Feb 26 02:01 quex-exe.py*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4074 Oct 13  2013 README
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   118 Mar 22 15:22 unit_test_results.txt
```

i also added `export QUEX_PATH=/opt/quex/quex-0.65.4/` to the `.bashrc`

```
ThinkPad-T430:~/tmp/OpenFST/tokenizer/trainable-tokenizer/src$ vim ~/.bashrc
ThinkPad-T430:~/tmp/OpenFST/tokenizer/trainable-tokenizer/src$ echo $QUEX_PATH 
/opt/quex/quex-0.65.4/
ThinkPad-T430:~/tmp/OpenFST/tokenizer/trainable-tokenizer/src$ sudo make install
[  6%] Building FeaturesReader with quex
Environment variable QUEX_PATH has not been defined.
error: environment variable 'QUEX_PATH' is not defined.
error: your system is 'posix'.
```

but still i get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue using the `-I` flag. I had to use `quex -I`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the real problem is that your python is python 3.0+
and not python 2.7 as required for Quex.

Admittedly, the error message does not tell this directly.

Comment: That's an hint I would take and may be try again.  I'll try with a different version of python.  I've voted up for the suggestion.  Will check if it works.

Comment: Nope. It didn't help.

Comment: In the Makefile, right before 'quex' is called. Could add the 'echo $QUEX_PATH' command. I would expect something like "quex -i ..." and change it to "echo $QUEX_PATH; quex -i ...". Then, copy-paste the results. BTW, Did you contact Jiri? This might be an issue with his Makefile.